# Не добавляется элемент innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Этот код работает в песочнице jsfiddle.net, но не работает на моём сайте. Элемент просто отсутствует. У меня конкретно не добавляется на сайт li id="night-mode", что на последней строчке кода ниже.

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    if (!('localStorage' in window)) return;
    var nightMode = localStorage.getItem('gmtNightMode');
    if (nightMode) {
        document.documentElement.className += ' night-mode';
    }
})(window, document);


;(function (window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    if (!('localStorage' in window)) return;

    var nav = document.querySelector('#menu-primary');
    if (!nav) return;


    nav.innerHTML += '<li id="night-mode"><a role="button" href="#">Ночной режим</a></li>';
```

Вот код html:

```
        <ul id="menu-primary">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: потому что Ваш код находитcя в странице выше элемента, который Вы ищете

Comment: Большое спасибо, это помогло!